# Нужна помощь с преобразованием Word в PDF на PHP

Tags: php, pdf, phpword, dompdf, tcpdf

Суть проблемы:
Есть Word документы, которые заполняются автоматически данными с формы, их нужно по нажатию кнопки преобразовывать в pdf

Пробовал сначала в HTML преобразовывать, но ломается структура, сильно ломается

Пробовал сразу в PDF, так же, структура снова сломана

Пробовал на PHPWord с DomPDF, TCPDF, но все равно лажа

Структура сломана в обоих случаях одинаково

В одном документе присутствует изображение и таблица, в другом только таблица

Ставить libreoffice на сервер не вариант

Рассчитываю на помощь

Все библиотеки ставил через композер, PHP последней версии

Comment: Не получается через код - используйте авто-кликер типа AutoIt или автоматизатор AutoHotKey.